# Can one find a colored simple closed curve in a colored plane?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have an infinite plane, each point colored in either red or blue.
Can one find a simple closed curve whose points have the same color?

If so, can we generalize this result into $n$-colored plane? If not, what coloring would give us a counterexample?

Comment: Please give some context for this problem.  Where does it arise?  What have you done on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colour point $(x,y)$ red if $x$ is rational, blue otherwise.  A monochromatic curve would have to be contained in a vertical line, and couldn't be a simple closed curve.